# How to loop background music while end game conditions are not met in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, while-loop, flash-cs6, background-music

I am fairly new to action script and need to know how to loop BG music. I know other languages you could do something like

```
    while(!endGame){
          sound.play();
}
```

but I can't seem to find the syntax for how to do this in AS, or maybe there is a better way? It's a 7 second clip so I need it to continue to loop until end conditions are met.

Answer (score 2):

AS3 provides two methods to deal with this. The most straightforward is telling the play command the number of times you want a sound to repeat using it's loops parameter.
https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#play()

The second method - which gives you more control - is a bit more complicated. Basically you're starting the sound and add a listener which monitors playback of the sound. If it finished playing a **SOUND_COMPLETE** event will fire and it's callback function can restart the playback.
To give you an example:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var sound:Sound;
        private var soundChannel:SoundChannel;

        public function Main():void
        {
            if (stage)
                init();
            else
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            sound = new Sound();
            var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("sound.mp3");
            sound.load(urlRequest);
           soundChannel = sound.play();
           soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundFinished);

        }

        public function soundFinished(event:Event):void
        {
            soundChannel.removeEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundFinished);
            soundChannel = sound.play();
            soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, soundFinished);
        }
    }
}
```